# How can I migrate a wcf client with federation binding from .net framework to .net core?

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core, ws-federation

I am migrating a WCF client from .Net Framework to .Net core. I am creating the client derived from ClientBase and using Federation Binding.

Here is binding creation code working in .Net Framework:

```
private Binding CreateBinding()
{
   var issuerBinding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport);
   issuerBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

   var binding = new WS2007FederationHttpBinding(WSFederationHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
   binding.Security.Message.IssuedKeyType = SecurityKeyType.SymmetricKey;
   binding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = false;
   binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;

   binding.Security.Message.IssuerAddress = new EndpointAddress(this.stsAddress);
   binding.Security.Message.IssuerBinding = issuerBinding;

   return binding
}
```

Here is corresponding code in .Net core:

```
private Binding CreateBinding()
{
   var issuerBinding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport);
   issuerBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

   var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(this.stsAddress);
   var tokenParameters = WSTrustTokenParameters.CreateWS2007FederationTokenParameters(issuerBinding, endpointAddress);
   tokenParameters.KeyType = SecurityKeyType.SymmetricKey;

   var binding = new WSFederationHttpBinding(tokenParameters);
   binding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = false;
   binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;

   return binding;
}
```

Unfortunately the .net core version does not work - calling the service throws 'The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.'

It turned out that the request to sts is failing.
I created a proxy to intercept the http requests and found following differences in the calls to the sts service:

1. the .net framework request contains following properties that are missing in .net core version:

```
<trust:KeyWrapAlgorithm>
   http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p
</trust:KeyWrapAlgorithm>
<trust:EncryptWith>
   http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc
</trust:EncryptWith>
<trust:SignWith>
   http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1
</trust:SignWith>
<trust:CanonicalizationAlgorithm>
   http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#
</trust:CanonicalizationAlgorithm>
<trust:EncryptionAlgorithm>
   http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc
</trust:EncryptionAlgorithm>
```

2. `trust:BinarySecret` element of `trust:Entropy` is different. The .net framework version contains type attribute `Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Nonce"` which is missing in the .net core version. According to the WS-Trust documentation the default value is SymmetricKey.
3. The .net core request contains `trust:TokenType` element which is missing in the .net framework version

```
<trust:TokenType>
   http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0
</trust:TokenType>
```

How can i set up a proper binding to make it work in .net core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the .net core WCF client didn't send the certificate with the request.
.net core checks if certificate has a private key and skips it if not.
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/fe7adb2bf92bba926268c2e9f562b11c84932a07/src/Common/src/System/Net/Security/CertificateHelper.cs#L39-L42

```
if (!cert.HasPrivateKey)
{
   continue;
}
```

I was getting the certificate from Azure Key Vault which by default returns it without the private key. Changing it to include the private key resolved the issue.

My .net framework application used the same method of getting the certificate (so it didn't have the private key either), but it was able to obtain the private key from my Local machine store where the certificate was installed.

Answer (score 0):

Core does not support Wshttpbinding, wcf only supports BasicHttpBinding, CustomBinding, NetHttpBinding, NetTcpBinding：

[image]

I suggest you continue to use the .net framework or modify the server-side binding.

For more information about WCF Features in core, you can refer to this [link](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/main/release-notes/SupportedFeatures-v2.1.0.md).

Comment: since the release of the 4.8.0 version of the System.ServiceModel.Federation package .net core supports WSHttpBinding
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/wsfederationhttpbinding-in-net-standard-wcf/